# how to get viewmodel's data in another activity from pagedlist to show viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewmodel, android-paging-library

I have used paging library to fetch data from server and shown it to Recyclerview.
i have used PageKeyedDataSource in Datasource class.
now i have to show the data in new activity's Viewpager when clicked on the Recyclerview item, and show next and previous data of that item when scrolling viewpager.
But my problem is that, i am unable to get PagedList data from Viewmodel to show on Viewpager, i am new in android and paging library, kindly suggest me some detailed solution, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by simply creating InstanceNameViewModel Factory

```
public class SingletonNameViewModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {


    NameViewModel t;

    public SingletonNameViewModelFactory() {
      //  t = provideNameViewModelSomeHowUsingDependencyInjection
    }

    @Override
    public NameViewModel create(Class<NameViewModel> modelClass) {
        return t;
    }
}
```

and using with
`mModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,myFactory).get(NameViewModel.class);`